# How to display items inline using angular's *ngFor

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, angular, ngfor

I am trying to display items inline instead of appearing in different row. Please see code and picture below. I have tried to look online for solutions but everyone else is asking a different use case. Please let me know. Thanks!

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>
        <div class="pimg1">
           <div class="ptext">
               <span class="borderStyle">
                   Kenny's Site
               </span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section section-light">
            <h2>Skills</h2>
            <p class="skills" *ngFor="let skill of skills">{{skill.skill}}</p>
        </section>
        <div class="pimg2">
           <div class="ptext">
               <span class="borderStyle">
                   Image2 Text
               </span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section section-dark">
           <h2>Section 1</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, saepe.</p>
       </section>
       <div class="pimg3">
           <div class="ptext">
               <span class="borderStyle">
                   Image3 Text
               </span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section section-dark">
           <h2>Section 3</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, saepe.</p>
       </section>
       <div class="pimg1">
           <div class="ptext">
               <span class="borderStyle">
                   Kenny's Site
               </span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Try changing the <p> to <div> tag

Comment: you skills are getting displayed in row only like javascript text 3 times each time in new row. what do you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's not an angular problem case here. 
you need to manage css to make skills displayed in flex or grid.

maybe you can try making all skills in a div container, and flex them.

html :

```
<section class="section section-light">
      <h2>Skills</h2>
      <div class="skill-list">
         <p class="skills" *ngFor="let skill of skills">{{skill.skill}}</p>
      </div>
 </section>
```

css :

```
.skill-list{
     display : flex;
     justify-content: between;
}
```

Comment: Hey don't mind but I want to add one thing here that there is no need to add flex-direction property as row because row is the default property of flex-direction. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use css flexbox pattern here.Try adding a class to your `<p>` tag and give them the following properties

```
.<your class name> {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if you don't want to mess around that much with CSS attributes you should have a look at [@angular/flex-layout][1]


          [1]: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

        1. Rows made like this: 
        <div fxLayout="row wrap">
          <div fxFlex="50%" [fxFlex.lt-md]="100%" fxLayoutAlign="start center">

          </div>
          <div fxFlex="50%" [fxFlex.lt-md]="100%" fxLayoutAlign="end center">

          </div>
        </div>

        2. Columns made like this:

        <div fxLayout="column wrap">
          <div fxFlex="50%" fxLayoutAlign="start center">

          </div>
          <div fxFlex="50%" fxLayoutAlign="end center">

          </div>
        </div>


    [fxFlex.lt-md] makes the styling responsive, depending on your current user's viewport. There are *.lt-sm, *.lt-md and also *.gt-sm and so on...

And you may use on any flexLayout directives like "fxLayoutAlign" and others...
```